# How to clear ComboBox text when DropdownStyle is DropDown

Tags: winforms, combobox

I have a ComboBox whose DropdownStyle is DropDown. So, I can select from the list or can type own data.

[image: Please see the image]

When I click on the clear button, text typed in the ComboxBox should be removed.
I have already tried "object.text = string.Empty;" but not working.

```
public ComboBox cmb_Identifier(int x, int y)
{
            cntrlObjList.comboBoxIdentifier.Items.Clear();
            cntrlObjList.comboBoxIdentifier.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            cntrlObjList.comboBoxIdentifier.FormattingEnabled = true;
            cntrlObjList.comboBoxIdentifier.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
            cntrlObjList.comboBoxIdentifier.Name = "cmbIdentifier";
            cntrlObjList.comboBoxIdentifier.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(151, 21);
            cntrlObjList.comboBoxIdentifier.TabIndex = 6;
            cntrlObjList.comboBoxIdentifier.Visible = true;
            cntrlObjList.comboBoxIdentifier.Items.Add("Identifier 1");
            cntrlObjList.comboBoxIdentifier.Items.Add("Identifier 2");
            return cntrlObjList.comboBoxIdentifier;
}

public void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        cntrlObjListMain.comboBoxIdentifier.SelectedText = string.Empty(); //not working

}
```

Comment: It would be usefull to have the code of how you are fill the combobox and also how do you try to delete it.

Comment: @BrankVictoria I have added code, please check it.

Comment: When you see the combobox for the first time, does it have a selected value? (Probably the first item) or it just blank?

Comment: Also, I guess that cmb_Identifier returns you the Combobox when you click on "cntrlObjList.comboBoxIdentifier" can you try to do "cntrlObjList.comboBoxIdentifier.Items.Clear();" in "btnClear_Click" and see if it works

Comment: `SelectedText` is for the current "highlighted" text.  You want `comboBoxIdentifier.Text = String.Empty;`  If the drop down is shown, it would take two clicks of the button to make that work: one to close the dropdown, two to clear the text.  Since you claimed you tried that already, it's most likely because the combo box or form you are referencing aren't the ones you see on the screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution and it is working in my case.

```
cntrlObjList.comboBoxIdentifier.Text = null;
```

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε I would request you please see stackoverflow user guide to know when a new user can accept/vote in for answers. I believe this may help you to comment on anyone else post or vote down.

Comment: *...if you have posted your approach to this problem*. What problem??? YOU HAVE SOLDED IT and he took YOUR solution and posted it as answer! Can't you see the times? He posted his "solution" 11 hours **after** you posted yours! And I didn't downvote you. On the contrary I upvoted you! I now think I made a mistake...

Answer (score -1):

The following should work for you

```
cntrlObjList.comboBoxIdentifier.Text = String.Empty;
```

or

```
cntrlObjList.comboBoxIdentifier.Text = "";
```

Comment: The question is already answered. You just copied it and presented it as yours.

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε rather then discouraging anyone, it would be more helpful if you have posted your approach to this problem.